The Ray Matrix (paraxial approximation)
I'm trying to figure out how to solve this question in my homework, where an optical fiber shoots out a beam into a glass sphere with a radius R. The optical fiber is placed in air, and the glass index is n_sp. The S12 matrix should be:
$$
S12 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{n_{sp}}-1 & \frac{2R}{n_sp} \\
-\frac{2(n_{sp}) -1}{n_{sp}R} & \frac{2}{n_{sp}}-1 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

I attempted to find the S12 matrix by implementing the R1, T12, and R2 matrices, then multiplying them together. I also tried to account for the sign convention but am unsure if it has been implemented correctly. I hope to get some help in identifying where my calculations might be going wrong. I can see that my A, B coefficients in the S12 is correct.
Calculation:
$$
R1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\frac{1-n_{sp}}{n_{sp}R} & \frac{1}{n_{sp}} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
T12 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2R \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
R2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-\frac{1-n_{sp}}{n_{sp}R} & \frac{1}{n_{sp}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
S12 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-n_{sp}+2}{n_{sp}} & \frac{2R}{n_{sp}} \\
-\frac{(-1+n_{sp})^2}{n_{sp}^2R} & \frac{-1+2n_{sp}}{n_{sp}^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.
